# Race Condition On Save Event

Tags: java, database, race-condition

I have two different endpoints like:

```
endpoint1 => /api/user
endpoint2 => /api/user/roles
```

Imagine that these two endpoints call same method at the same time.

```
public List activeRoles(userId) {
   var roles = repository.findAllRolesOfUser(userId);

   if (roles == null) {
      var role = new Role("DEFAULT", userId);
      repository.save(role);
      
      return Arrays.asList(role)
   } else {
      return roles;
   }
}
```

When I call activeRoles(userId) method from endpoint1 and endpoint2 at the same time, it causes race condition and "DEFAULT" role is created twice in the database. Is there a way to avoid it?

Note: I cannot use unique constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **syncronized** in java.

```
public List activeRoles(userId) {
   var roles = repository.findAllRolesOfUser(userId);

   if (roles == null) {
      var role = new Role("DEFAULT", userId);
      save(role);
      
      return Arrays.asList(role)
   } else {
      return roles;
   }
}

private syncronized void save(data) {
     var role = repository.findBy(...);
     
     if (!role) {
        repository.save(data);
     }
}
```